Trend and Residue plots in seasonal decompose not spanning entire duration of data
I am performing SARIMAX forecasting and visualizing the seasonal decompose plots. I have monthly data running from Jan 1, 2022 to March 1, 2024. When I plot my data I am getting a "partial" trend and residue plots.
Sample Data:
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from matplotlib import pyplot

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2022-01-01', end='2024-03-01', freq='MS'),
         data = {'rev' : np.random.randint(10, high = 1000, size = len(pd.date_range('2022-01-01', end='2024-03-01', freq='MS')))})

seasonal_decompose(df).plot();


But when I do the same for data with longer time span, the plot seems to better span the time line.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', end='2024-03-01', freq='MS'),
         data = {'rev' : np.random.randint(10, high = 1000, size = len(pd.date_range('2015-01-01', end='2024-03-01', freq='MS')))})

seasonal_decompose(df1).plot();


Could someone please help me understand if my understanding is right, if so, what would be the way to understand the trend plot where we don't have data for sufficiently long duration.

Your understanding is correct; with a shorter DF, you're getting a shorter plot (of course).
The complexity isn't in the python code, it's in the statistical model; since a SARIMAX model (or even just an AR/MA model for that matter) predicts the current value based on p previous values, it is impossible to calculate results for the first p observations. If I'm interpreting the docs and the plots you showed correctly, seasonal_decompose will default to use half a year of lags when providing monthly data (p = 6).
Furthermore, seasonal_decompose uses a two-sided moving average by default (see the docs again). If you turn this off, you'll find that the trend data only has missing values at the start, not at the end of the dataset.
As for how to understand the trend plot: as you would with any SARIMAX model (The docs make it sound like this is actually just an MAX model, not a whole SARIMAX model, but that's besides the point). The trend is the result of fitting the model to the data, except for the seasonal effects. The model just doesn't yield any information about this trend for the outermost p observations.

So regardless of the time line, the model will use 6 months data at either end of the data to arrive at the trend when working with monthly data?

I'm not sure, you'd have to dive into the documentation or the source code to figure that specifically out I'm afraid.
